# Evaluate$\int_0^{\infty}x^4e^{-3x}\; dx$ using the change of variable: $t=3x$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been given the hint that I need to use integration by parts more than once in order to get the answer. However, I can't seem to get a reasonable result.

Comment: Well, what happens when you use integration by parts once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $t=3x$, then $dt=3dx$ and $x^4=\frac{t^4}{3^4}$, so we have:
$\int x^4e^{-3x}dx = \frac{1}{3^5}\int t^4e^{-t}dt$. And then use integration by parts many times until you solve it.

Answer (score 1):

set $$-3x=t$$ then we have $$x=-\frac{1}{3}t$$ and $$dx=-\frac{1}{3}dt$$ and then do integration by parts